# affect/effect did I get it right?

Tags: verbs

> The effect of light from the sun had the affect of allowing john to see further.

True, not true? *Effect* is a verb, so light is an *effect*: *affect* alters something, so john seeing further was the *affect* of lights *effects*??????????

Comment: _affect_ is a verb unless it's used to mean an emotion or desire. You can't put _the_ before a verb.

Answer (score 1):

Not true.

> The effect of light from the sun had the effect of allowing John to see farther.

If you wanted to use "affect" as a verb ("to modify")...

> The effect of light from the sun affected the distance to which John could see.

If you wanted to use "effect" as a verb ("to cause to exist")...

> The light from the sun effected a greater viewing distance for John.

As a noun, "affect" is often limited to psychological applications.

Comment: I'm not sure it's really worth posting an answer *here* when there are a couple of perfectly good ones on the original - but thanks for calling attention to the dup (I take it you don't yet have the rep to actually closevote yourself).