# Which is correct? Affect/effect

Tags: grammar

The animals will have an **affect** over your life.

The animals will have an **effect** over your life.

Comment: The answer can be found in a dictionary.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I did already but I still don't know...

Comment: See the usage note here: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/affect I don't think anyone here could explain it more clearly.

Comment: @michael.hor257k My original thought was to use 'effect' but after looking at both for awhile I'm confused lol.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Hey Michael, think you can help me out with this one? I know you guys don't like giving answers but I've been working on writing papers all day and I'm delusional. I just need some confirmation.

Comment: duplicates https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/232191/affect-effect-did-i-get-it-right and https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315/effect-vs-affect  If you want a quick answer, "The animals will have an effect over your life" is correct.

Comment: Also there are more questions asking about thison ELL (English Language Learners) Stack Exchange site. You can find them by searching "effect affect". Also an internet search might help, here's Grammarist site https://grammarist.com/usage/affect-effect and Grammarly site https://www.grammarly.com/blog/affect-vs-effect/

Answer (score 3):

The animals will have an affect over your life - This means that the animals will behave/feel a certain way for as long as you live. Presumably when you die they will behave/feel differently.

The animals will have an effect on your life - This means that the animals will change your life in some way.